# Video doesn't loop Android VideoView

Tags: android, loops, android-videoview

I am trying to build an android app that will loop a video!
The problem is that it never loops! It plays the video only once! 
During debugging i realized that the "myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener" is being executed but the video doesn't play!
I also try "mp.reset()" inside the CompletionListener.
Maybe i am missing something in a different file, such as the Manifest?

Any thoughts?
Here is my code:

```
  final VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
      myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));     

       myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                myVideoView.requestFocus();
                myVideoView.start();
           }
        });
       myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                 myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));

           }
        });
```

Comment: do not need to set the same URI or path again just write myVideoView.start();

Answer (score 15):

Try `onPreparedListener` instead of `onCompletionListener`:

```
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Probably can remove "TODO Auto-generated method stub"

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
myVideoView.setVideoPath(video_path); 
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.start();   

myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        myVideoView.start();  

    }
});
```

By that after completion of your video start again...

Comment: this is good but onCompletion must seekTo 1


@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.seekTo(1); 
        myVideoView.start();  

    }

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
            videoView.setVideoPath(tempFileMessageUri.toString());

            ctlr = new MediaController(context);
            ctlr.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

            videoView.setMediaController(ctlr);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();

            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });

            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoView.start();

                }
            });
```