# Video not looping on device, but looping OK in emulator

Tags: java, android

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246838/video-doesnt-loop-android-videoview) code but after installed in device my video doesn't loop. Any other solution?
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

You need to start again this video....

Try this.

```
VideoView myVideoView;
```

in onCreate()

```
myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
myVideoView.setVideoPath(video_path); 
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.start();   

myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

      myVideoView.start();  

   }
});
```

start again in OnCompletionListener, because after completion of your video automatically re-start.

Comment: I add Initial code for VideoView in my answer... remove your old code and use this....because I already use this and its working perfect...