# setLooping(true) is not working in jellybean and kitkat

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

i am developing an app which play video from URL, to control video i also add mediacontroller.

i want that video play in endless loop, so i added following below code to mediaplayer

```
`mp.setLooping(true);`
```

inside
 `videoview.setOnPreparedListener` method

But `setLoop(true)` method not working in jellybean and kitkat device.
It work in Android M and above version. 
I not debug in android L because i do not have Emulator yet of it.

i also go through [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping(boolean)) document, they mentioned that `setLooping(true)` is added in API 1 but it not working  in android K and J

help me to solve above problem

below is my full code

```
public void videoStup(final ProgressBar pb, final VideoView videoview)
    {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        try
        {
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(this.videoview);
            mediacontroller.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            //mediacontroller.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);
            videoview.seekTo(100);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "error = "+e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                videoview.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246838/video-doesnt-loop-android-videoview

Comment: @NileshRathod my looping is working in android M and it's above version , it not work in android K and J

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem with the help of below code, now it work in Android jellybean & Android Kitkat also

i only thing i need to called resume method after video complete.

here is my code

```
videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {

            Log.d(TAG,"onCompletion");
            videoview.resume();

        }
    });
```